# How to Detect workstation/System Screen Lock/unlock in windows OS using java?

Tags: java, windows

I'm trying to note down workstation/System screen Lock and Unlock of each employee working in windows OS. I needed to store these record in a DataBase, using JAVA. I have searched all over and got on idea how to do it using JAVA. where ever I searched I get code for VB only.

Comment: Have you find a solution? I'm having the same need today...

Comment: @André yes, but we did it using .Net; since its a lengthy process in java and also we need to use JNI, C# ,C++. so that we can create a .dll file which can be used in our java code, which is a pain full work. So I dropped this idea for going java solution.

Comment: @Andre if you want java solution follow the answer that which I had accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JNI (Java Native Interface) to invoke functions from the Windows system dll.

Here is the sample code for use of functions which check workstation locking state: http://brutaldev.com/post/2008/05/23/Checking-if-the-workstation-is-locked.aspx

And here is the article about invoking dll-functions from Java via JNI:
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20679

Comment: I have gone through those links you gave, but I need to do it in pure java. I have understand that there is no use of coding java for this scenario because inserted of converting java file to a header file, its better to code it in C or C++ itself or any of windows based code like VB or any.?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no pure java solution for this task. The only possible way is to use Java + JNI + call to system dll files.

Comment: This perhaps worked once but under Windows 10 does not work.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it in pure Java using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna). Add **jna.jar** and **jna-platform.jar** to your project. And in this file [com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32WindowDemo](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/native_window_msg/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Win32WindowDemo.java) there is a full example of lock and unlock listener and much more. Here is the necessary code from thah Win32WindowDemo:

```
public class WorkstationLockListening implements WindowProc
{

    /**
     * Instantiates a new win32 window test.
     */
    public WorkstationLockListening()
    {
        // define new window class
        final WString windowClass = new WString("MyWindowClass");
        final HMODULE hInst = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle("");

        WNDCLASSEX wClass = new WNDCLASSEX();
        wClass.hInstance = hInst;
        wClass.lpfnWndProc = WorkstationLockListening.this;
        wClass.lpszClassName = windowClass;

        // register window class
        User32.INSTANCE.RegisterClassEx(wClass);
        getLastError();

        // create new window
        final HWND hWnd = User32.INSTANCE.CreateWindowEx(User32.WS_EX_TOPMOST, windowClass, "'TimeTracker hidden helper window to catch Windows events", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, // WM_DEVICECHANGE contradicts parent=WinUser.HWND_MESSAGE
                null, hInst, null);

        getLastError();
        System.out.println("window sucessfully created! window hwnd: " + hWnd.getPointer().toString());

        Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd, Wtsapi32.NOTIFY_FOR_THIS_SESSION);

        MSG msg = new MSG();
        while (User32.INSTANCE.GetMessage(msg, hWnd, 0, 0) != 0)
        {
            User32.INSTANCE.TranslateMessage(msg);
            User32.INSTANCE.DispatchMessage(msg);
        }

            /// This code is to clean at the end. You can attach it to your custom application shutdown listener
            Wtsapi32.INSTANCE.WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification(hWnd);
            User32.INSTANCE.UnregisterClass(windowClass, hInst);
            User32.INSTANCE.DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            System.out.println("program exit!");
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32.WindowProc#callback(com.sun.jna.platform .win32.WinDef.HWND, int, com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM, com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM)
     */
    public LRESULT callback(HWND hwnd, int uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
            case WinUser.WM_DESTROY:
            {
                User32.INSTANCE.PostQuitMessage(0);
                return new LRESULT(0);
            }
            case WinUser.WM_SESSION_CHANGE:
            {
                this.onSessionChange(wParam, lParam);
                return new LRESULT(0);
            }
            default:
                return User32.INSTANCE.DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the last error.
     * 
     * @return the last error
     */
    public int getLastError()
    {
        int rc = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError();

        if (rc != 0)
            System.out.println("error: " + rc);

        return rc;
    }

    /**
     * On session change.
     * 
     * @param wParam
     *            the w param
     * @param lParam
     *            the l param
     */
    protected void onSessionChange(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (wParam.intValue())
        {
            case Wtsapi32.WTS_SESSION_LOCK:
            {
                this.onMachineLocked(lParam.intValue());
                break;
            }
            case Wtsapi32.WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK:
            {
                this.onMachineUnlocked(lParam.intValue());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * On machine locked.
     * 
     * @param sessionId
     *            the session id
     */
    protected void onMachineLocked(int sessionId)
    {
        System.out.println("Machine locked right now!");
    }

    /**
     * On machine unlocked.
     * 
     * @param sessionId
     *            the session id
     */
    protected void onMachineUnlocked(int sessionId)
    {
        System.out.println("Machine unlocked right now!");
    }
}
```

We have solved this problem in [Google Group Workstation Lock / Unlock listener](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jna-users/hNYm9NNQgCg). You can find there my own implementation but this code right here is much better! Enjoy :)

Comment: @ Ladislav Gallay I'm trying your above implementation but I have error in MainWindow. It says cannot be resolve to a type. What I've to import for it(any external jars)?

Comment: @Crawler That would be a class in jna.jar. Make sure you add both jna.jar files to your class path then your IDE should be able to find it for you.

Comment: @Crawler Ahh sorry, I had unused attribute in `public WorkstationLockListening(MainWindow window)`. I already edited my answer and removed it. It was my custom project class which has nothing to do with this demo.

Comment: This was the simplest & cleanest solution I could find online for detecting system lock & unlock using java.. deserve more upvotes :)

Answer (score 4):

One more way, without any windows system libs, ect.

Main idea - screenshots for locked PC will be totally black, so you can take one and simply check that some critical points are black

*-16777216 - magic number, that means FFFFFFFFFF000000xH and last 00 00 00 means RGB color code (actually black color)*

```
        BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        boolean isBlack;    
        isBlack = (image.getRGB(1,1)==-16777216)
                &(image.getRGB(1,image.getHeight()-1)==-16777216)
                &(image.getRGB(image.getWidth()-1,1)==-16777216)
                &(image.getRGB(image.getWidth()-1,image.getHeight()-1)==-16777216)
                &(image.getRGB(image.getWidth()/2,image.getHeight()/2)==-16777216);
        return isBlack;
```

Actually, there could be only one case with incorrect lock identification - when you have totally black wallpaper, with hidden taskbar and hidden icons.

Comment: I'm finding that locked screens are not black.  Also, what if they're watching a movie full screen and it has a completely black frame?

Comment: Instead of `-16777216` you could simply use: `Color.BLACK.getRGB()` - same value! :) - by the way: it works like a charm for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

With JDK9 (JDK11) you can use java.awt.Desktop :

```java
Desktop tempDesktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
tempDesktop.addAppEventListener(new UserSessionListener() {

    @Override
    public void userSessionDeactivated(UserSessionEvent aE) {
        LOG.info("Desktop:userSessionDeactivated Reason=" + aE.getReason() + " Source=" + aE.getSource());
            // Windows Key L: 
            // Tue Aug 31 11:22:49 CEST 2021:info:MainController:userSessionDeactivated Reason=LOCK

            // Close Lid:
            // Tue Aug 31 11:24:38 CEST 021:info:MainController:userSessionDeactivated Reason=LOCK
            // Tue Aug 31 11:24:39 CEST 2021:info:MainController:systemAboutToSleep Source=java.awt.Desktop@741f67cd

        ptcUserStatus = PtcUserStatus.AWAY;
    }

    @Override
    public void userSessionActivated(UserSessionEvent aE) {
        LOG.info("Desktop:userSessionActivated Reason=" + aE.getReason() + " Source=" + aE.getSource());
            // Logon after Windows Key L
            // Tue Aug 31 11:22:53 CEST 2021:info:MainController:userSessionActivated Reason=LOCK

            // Open Lid:
            // Tue Aug 31 11:24:56 CEST 2021:info:MainController:systemAwoke Source=java.awt.Desktop@741f67cd
            // Tue Aug 31 11:25:06 CEST 2021:info:MainController:userSessionActivated Reason=LOCK
        ptcUserStatus = PtcUserStatus.BACK;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Unlock Administrator](http://www.e-motional.com/ULAdmin.htm)

The purpose of the program is allow the admin at assign who can unlock the computer but it also has logging capability.  It also allows you to run a script whenever the computer is locked or unlocked.  This may be helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry. I'm looking for pure java idea.

Answer (score 0):

Using JDIC Library,

To Check the system is Locked or Not

> SystemInfo.isSessionLocked()

Comment: I did not find any downloads to include JDIC Library. How to use it and where can I find it?

Comment: JDIC is the java.net project.. u may find the free source over there in repo. download and bulid by urself using ANT.

I tried All the distributions and downloaded from internet a month back..

Comment: @Sathish if u didnt find the jars... ping me @ p.r.c.prabhu@gmail.com.. in send you.