# How to lock and unlock windows 10 system using Java source code?

Tags: java

I want to lock and unlock system using java. Can anyone assist me with Java source code. How to implement or any other ways to achieve this task?

'------ This is my own PC and I have userid and password ----------

I am looking instead of manual input. I can pass the my userid and password in program and it will login my system to unlock pc. Not sure this can be possible, however your opinion any suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Use a `Robot` to press the lock keys (Windows + L) and then the unlock keys (CTRL + ALT + DEL). But the unlock should be done by a human

Comment: I am trying to achieve this task by using Java.

Comment: He means `java.awt.Robot` not a real robot ;)

Comment: Have you already checked whether there is an Windows API to do this task? If so than your second step would be to do this in java.

Comment: I did some research and found below relavant links 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228145/how-to-detect-workstation-system-screen-lock-unlock-in-windows-os-using-java  But still not use. Need here expert advice how to start this task.

Comment: As far as locking goes, trying to programatically (with Robot) press windows+L does print L, but not lock the session. I'm unsure why.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcut for locking your workstation is `%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe  user32.dll,LockWorkStation`, so by doing the following, you should be able to lock your workstation:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process pr = rt.exec("C:/WINDOWS/System32/rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As for unlocking, I highly doubt it's possible, but good luck.

*Furthermore, if it was possible to unlock a workstation programatically, that would be a pretty big security flaw.*