# Java Application must be closed when in sleep mode

Tags: java

I want to keep my application stopped if computer goes to sleep mode. I have use thread in my application and it performs some task after specific interval.

**Is it possible to stop program execution when the computer sleep?**

If yes, please provide some solution or Java classes for the same.

Comment: I think your java code would need to interact with the operating system of the host computer. Is there a specific operating system that you are targeting? Windows? Linux? MacOS?

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10228145/how-to-detect-workstation-system-screen-lock-unlock-in-windows-os-using-java

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not using Java. You'd have to write an operating system hook (in say C++) that triggers on whatever signal your operating system sends when it puts the computer to sleep and then tries to gracefully shut down your Java program (probably by sending it some sort of a message on a TCP port that your program will listen to).